# TextInputAction.newline does not work on custom keyboards, only on the GBoard

Tags: flutter

TextInputAction.newline does not work on custom keyboards, only on the Google keyboard, when I press the Enter key on custom keyboards, nothing happens.

```
TextField(
  focusNode: focusNode,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
  style: Theme.of(context)
      .textTheme
      .subtitle1!
      .copyWith(fontSize: config.s17),
  onChanged: (text) {
    feedbackBloc.add(MessageChangedEvent(text));
  },
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
  maxLength: 2000,
  buildCounter: (
    context, {
    required currentLength,
    required isFocused,
    maxLength,
  }) =>
      null,
  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: tr('settings.how'),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      color: grayTextColor,
      fontSize: config.s17,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: so what's the question? as error says you must use Google keyboard to use New line functionality

Comment: @quim What error? 
People use not only the keyboard from Google